# sql query to get count of records

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have "Result" column in my table. Result column contains one of the below three values, 
Pass, Fail, Incomplete.
I need to write a query which gives below three results
1. total count of passed records
2. total count of failed records
3. total count of incomplete records

Is it possible? If yes, please guide me to write it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you storing that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'Pass' THEN 1 END) AS passed,
        COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'Failed' THEN 1 END) AS failed,
        COUNT(CASE result WHEN 'Incomplete' THEN 1 END) AS incomplete
FROM    mytable
```